# How to go back to previous detached head's commit on Git?

Tags: git, github

I lost my code on a detached head when I switched back to master head. I lost all my important code!

How can I go back to the code state of "commit: 21JUL2018 12:36am question reply, radio btn upto toast"?

Please check the `git reflog` here:

[image: reflog]

Comment: We need more information.  Please include the actual `reflog` text or at least the relevant parts, not just a link to the text.

Comment: You can find relevant info under .git/refs/heads/{your-branch-name}. Add the commit you are interested in into this file, as first line. This commit represents the head of a branch. That way, you can restore a "detached" head from a branch

Answer (score 0):

> How can I go back to the code state of "commit: 21JUL2018 12:36am question reply, radio btn upto toast" ??

Your reglog mentions that commit with the short SHA1 be01747, so...

```
git stash
git checkout be01747
```

That would restore the working tree and index of that commit (make sure you don't have any local modification in progress)
The HEAD would be detached again: you can create a new branch from there.

Note that it restore the commit content, not the local modification that were not yet added or committed.

Comment: I did this, and it says:$ git checkout be01747
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
        .idea/workspace.xml
Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
Aborting
.. then I did add and commit but didn't get back my previous codes, please help

Comment: @NabilaTajrin Did you add and commit your previous code?

Comment: If you did a commit, with git log, you should see it. Then you can cherry-pick your commit on master of instance.

Answer (score 0):

Stash your local changes first if you have local modifications by using git stash 
Then use git checkout be01747 to go to a previous commit, you can go to any previous commit by using the commit id.